# How to map external subdomain to my subdomain?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, apache-2.4, cloudflare

My company develops marketing reporting application and one of the requirements is that each user gets new subdomain created for their dashboard (*e.g **client.application.com***).

Once it's made, they configure their DNS to create new subdomain (*e.g **reports.client.com***) so that newly created subdomain on their domain point to our subdomain we created for them.

*In a nutshell, client needs to map their subdomain to our subdomain.*

Is this even possible with DNS?

Comment: They would just need to create a cname in their DNS to point to the subdomain that you created for them, or another record that gets them to the right server/ip

Comment: I did, but for some reason, user arrives on root domain of my application, not a subdomain.

Comment: There are lots of moving parts here, it could be a DNS issue, it could be cloudflare, it could be nginx/apache configs. Really the questions needs more details. A real working example would also help lots. Start by adding the nginx/apache configs, as they are hitting the server but the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out:

We:

- Create new vhost reports.client.com on our server

Client:

- Creates DNS 'A' record with 'reports' value pointing to our IP
- Creates new 'reports' subdomain

After propagation everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't created a virtual server for the `reports.client.com` domain name.

Although there are DNS names for `client.application.com` and `reports.client.com`, only the latter is used to access the application from the client.

The application needs to know that name, and in Apache you would use a `ServerAlias` and in `nginx` you would use a `server_name` directive.

In the absence of a matching name for `reports.client.com`, the default server will be used instead.